# Why don't I need to install JS before installing npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why don't I need to install Javascript before being able to install + use npm, just like I need to install Java before being able to install/use Maven?

Answer (score 2):

You have terminology mixed up. NodeJS isn't a package manager or build tool. It's a runtime for JavaScript. If you want to compare NodeJS to a Java equivalent, compare it to the JRE or JDK, not to Maven.

Comment: Ohk, thanks Joseph! and what is the Maven equivalent for Javascript?

Comment: Probably something like npm.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! - updated my question, so, why there is no need to install js before installing npm?

Comment: @SmritiMittal There is such a need. NPM won't work without NodeJS.

Comment: wait. but nodejs is not js. why will npm not work without nodejs?

Comment: What other JS runtime would you want NPM to use? Your browser?

Comment: so, are we saying that nodejs interprets npm? what does interpreting npm mean? ...

Answer (score 2):

Installing Nodejs is the equivalent because Nodejs includes the V8 Engine under the hood, which reads and interprets the js code you write. Maven only handles dependencies.